# PHP: array_push on multidimensional arrays and display its elements

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

My current project consist of multidimensional arrays in which it holds a date and some text contents.

i already used the normal arrays in my project and array_push is used for inserting an element to array. no i'm stuck in multidimensional array in which i don't know how to insert and display multi dimensional array(beginner to multi dimensional arrays).

i found a lot of results from stackoverflow itself, but none of them helped for me. i created a multidimensional array like this

```
$complaints = array(
    $each_complaints => array(
            "date" => "",
            "text" => ""
            )
 );
```

then i want to add data's into this array on the loop of mysql result

```
<?php foreach($query_56 as $notes):
          // eg: array_push " $notes->date , $notes->corresponding_text "
endforeach; ?>
```

and i want to display the array like this

```
array[date][text]=> [2014-11-18] [1st complaint]
array[date][text]=> [2015-01-15] [2nd complaint]
```

how can i achieve this, im begginer to multi dimesional arrays.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your current array structure prints like this 
Array
(
    [] => Array
        (
            [date] => 
            [text] => 
        )

)
The index of the array is blank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php foreach($query_56 as $key=>$notes):
       $each_complaints[$key]["date"] = $notes->date;
       $each_complaints[$key]["text"] = $notes->corresponding_text ;           
endforeach;

echo "<pre>";print_r($each_complaints);
?>
**Output :** 
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [date] => 01-11-2014
        [text] => rrrrrr
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [date] => 02-11-2014
        [text] => fffff
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [date] => 03-11-2014
        [text] => ddddd
    )

)
```

Comment: Thank you raj for instant reply. goal achived :) but shows an error too " Undefined variable: each_complaints " on line no: 5 , but the line no: 5 is the array declaration

Comment: @ShifanaMubi : just declare $each_complaints = array(); before foreach loop